# Sorting filenames using regular expressions

Tags: ruby, regex, sorting

I have a directory that contains 200 files (.txt) and I'm looking to sort them using a regular expression on a certain part of the filename.

Example file names are:

```
W:/name/2014-09-02 - name/20140902-070343_1-P4.txt
W:/name/2014-09-02 - name/20140902-070343_10-P4.txt
W:/name/2014-09-02 - name/20140902-070343_2-P4.txt
W:/name/2014-09-02 - name/20140902-070343_200-P4.txt
```

Which are in the same format in the array.

The code below will store the filenames in an array. I'm then looking to sort using a regular expression on the `_1`, `_200`, `_10` `_2` part of the file name.

```
require 'FileUtils'
contents = Dir.glob("W:/name/2014-09-02 - name/*.txt").select { |f| f.include?('P4')}.sort_by! {|s|  s[/(\D\d+)-P4.txt/]}
puts contents
```

With the above code I'm getting:

```
_1
_10
_100
_101
_102
.
.
.
_11
_111
```

When what I want is:

```
_1
_2
_3
_4
_5
.
.
.
_10
_11
```

Ultimately, Ill then want to loop through the array to confirm the incrementing value is continuous (1 - 200).

Comment: Convert the numeric part to an actual number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[
  "W:/name/2014-09-02 - name/20140902-070343_1-P4.txt",
  "W:/name/2014-09-02 - name/20140902-070343_10-P4.txt",
  "W:/name/2014-09-02 - name/20140902-070343_2-P4.txt",
  "W:/name/2014-09-02 - name/20140902-070343_200-P4.txt",
]
.sort_by{|s| s[/(?<=_)\d+/].to_i}
```

Result

```
[
  "W:/name/2014-09-02 - name/20140902-070343_1-P4.txt",
  "W:/name/2014-09-02 - name/20140902-070343_2-P4.txt",
  "W:/name/2014-09-02 - name/20140902-070343_10-P4.txt",
  "W:/name/2014-09-02 - name/20140902-070343_200-P4.txt"
]
```

Comment: That worked as expected, can you provide some info on what [/(?<=_)\d+/] is doing?

Comment: is it ignoring anything before _ ?

Comment: `(?<=_)` is called a ["positive lookbehind"](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). It ensures that the text matching `\d+` is immediately preceded by `_`. Positive and negative lookaheads and lookbehinds ("lookarounds") are "zero-width", meaning that they are not part of the match.  [String#to_i](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-to_i) converts (say) `"10-P4.txt"` to `10`. See also [String#[\]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D). sawa is up to his usual clever self.